# How to compare char arrays and then replace values

Tags: java

I have a string then i created a char[ ] using that string

```
String full = "This is the full text";
    char[ ] abc = full.toCharArray();
```

I also have a second char[ ] of all the vowels

```
char[] vowels = {'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'y'};
```

i want to compare an element from my first char[ ] abc to the vowels char[ ]  (i want to see if abc[ i ] is a vowel) if it is a vowel i want to replace it with the next letter in the vowel[ ].
Can someone please explain to me how I can do that.

Comment: Please post what you have tried, and we could help with why is it not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a helper method which would:

- Take a `char` as input
- Iterate through each vowel in `vowels` array
- Compare if `vowel == input char`
- Return next letter of the vowel if the above comparison is true
- Return `input char` if the comparison is false

Now you call this method with `abc[0]` as parameter to get back the next vowel, if it is a vowel. Then simply assign `abc[0] = <next vowel returned>`.

Your method signature could look like:

```
public char getNextCharacter(char c);
```

Implementation of this method is left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: Further improvement would be getNextCharacter(char c);  If it is a vowel, return next one, if not return c.